# Fullscreen Keyboard for Android app by Phonegap build

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

**Problem :-** I am developing an android application which has got 2 fields. When focus on the fields, virtual keyboard will hide/overlaped on these field. So from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137348/page-content-dont-scroll-whent-keyboard-shows-phonegap) I found the solution `<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />`. But it will result in STATUS BAR will shown and UI will pushed upwards. Hence, I reverted back.

**Question :-** Is there any jQuery patch or phonegap plugin to make virtual keyboard full screen [*both Landscape and Portrait mode* ] as you can see below image  :

[image: Full screen android keyboard]

Please reply as soon as possible! Thanks in Advance.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved this problem with below jQuery Patch :

```
//JS : OnReady event:

 var windowHeightSeventyPercent = parseInt(screen.height * 0.7); //To support multiple devices

 $("input").focusin(function(){
    $("body").height($("body").height()+parseInt(windowHeightSeventyPercent)); //Make page body scroll by adding height to make user to fillup field.
 });

 $("input").focusout(function(){
    $("body").height($("body").height()-parseInt(windowHeightSeventyPercent));
 });
```