# In Phonegap The input is covered by the keyboard once tap the input field

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

tapping on the text input at the bottom of the page, a virtual keyboard appears (as expected). The problem is that the virtual keyboard overlaps the focused text input. So while I type, I can't see what is being typed. I also cannot scroll down further to the bottom to see the text box, because the page always snaps back up. I am using version of Phonegap 3.5 and jquery 1.9.1

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by `focusin` and `focusout` jquery methods :

```
//JS : OnReady event:

var windowHeightSeventyPercent = parseInt(screen.height * 0.7); //To support multiple devices

$("input").focusin(function(){
    $("body").height($("body").height()+parseInt(windowHeightSeventyPercent)); //Make page body scroll by adding height to make user to fillup field.
});

$("input").focusout(function(){
  $("body").height($("body").height()-parseInt(windowHeightSeventyPercent));
});
```

**[Please refer this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385689/fullscreen-keyboard-for-android-app-by-phonegap-build)**

Comment: After applied you fix still having same problem can you look into this link. http://jsfiddle.net/4dLwezw1/3/

Comment: Are you using `Phonegap Build` ?  If so, kindly share `config.xml` file? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below preference to config.xml

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```