# Page doesn't scroll when keyboard shows in phonegap. Solution with fullscreen?

Tags: android, css, html, cordova

When the keyboard pops out it hides the input field and you cannot see what you are typing. There is some old [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137348/page-content-dont-scroll-whent-keyboard-shows-phonegap/17104491#17104491) which works by setting fullscreen to false in config.xml, but then you have the status bar visible. I tried with different options for windowSoftInputMode without success. Is there any way to fix this while keeping the fullscreen?

Comment: interesting topic, did you give the combination of this preferences setting and the statusbar-plugin(https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) a try? The statusbar might be gone when calling StatusBar.hide() while you are in fullscreen mode.

Comment: I just tried it. When the status bar is visible the scroll works after I call StatusBar.hide() the status bar hides and the scroll doesn't work. How could there be such a major phonegap problem without solution?