# ionic: adjustPan partially working on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

I have a problem using the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` in my ionic 1 app.
It works fine on iOS but it doesn't scroll in Android hiding the input field sometimes.

I'm using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my Manifest and these are my input fields

```
<label class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" ng-model="user.email">
</label>
```

Fullscreen is disabled in `config.xml` but enabling it as suggested [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/) doesn't work too.

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Any tip on how to solve this?

[image][image]

Comment: Have you tested to put options in config.xml instead of AndroidManifest ? And also this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23155069/2549619

Comment: Yes but nothing is happened..

Comment: @DevidFarinelli were you able to solve this issue?